# Debug igraph algorithm performance on R

Tags: r, performance-testing, igraph

I'm running several community detection algorithms using igraph package on R: Leading eigenvector, fastgreedy, etc.
My goal is to debug these algorithm performance on different datasets (such as small world, SBM, etc.).
I'm mainly interested in run time, memory consumption (cache, disk), etc.

Is there a way to debug the result of the algorithms? I saw the arpack package (used by igraph) has an option to output the trace and enable debugging. Is it possible to activate it via the igraph api?

I'd appreciate any help

Comment: `?microbenchmark` for timing.  `?utils::memory.size` for the obvious.

Comment: From what i understand these two specify parameters when typed. They don't allow for monitoring throughout the algorithm process, and therefore will not be helpful in comparing different algorithms/datasets.

Comment: OK, then `utils::Rprof and Rprofmem` may be closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: @user3370773: I am not sure what you mean. `microbenchmark` can measure the running time of any expression. This is not an igraph specific question, btw. Please read: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/ *Performant code*

Comment: I agree, and i've tried using R performance tools (microbenchmark, lineprof). However, when using these tools on the igraph package the result is usually a summary of the function. I would like to do some profiling of the steps within the igraph functions. For example, when using leading.eigenvector.community() i can see the time the whole function ran, or see the amount of memory the results allocates (very little). I would like to see the amount of time each iteration ran, and the amount of memory the complete matrix allocated in memory.

Comment: Then run it for one iteration only, then two, three, ten, and you'll have an idea. I am not sure what you mean by "the complete matrix", `leading.eigenvector.community` allocates a matrix for the merges, but that is small, O(n).

Comment: I can't run the iterations one by one. leading.eigenvector.community does gets a graph object as input, and does the whole computation until convergence. The output is the communities themselves which don't allocate much memory. I guess the heavy calculation is building the matrix which is n^2 in the general case (less if sparse), and then iterating using the Arnold iteration on arpack. Ideally I would see how much memory this whole computation takes on different kind of graphs.

Comment: You can run arbitrary number of steps, see the `steps` argument. Again, AFAIK no big matrix is built anywhere. Here is a source, which matrix do you mean? https://github.com/igraph/igraph/blob/c699953e2dfa3793308a32acb3a254a76e1f1384/src/community.c#L1509 As for the memory footprint, you can compare the footprint of the whole R process and then compare it to an R session without the igraph call. Essentially any windows tool that reports the memory usage of a process is good for this.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. As for the big matrix, a N^2 sparse matrix is built in all algorithms. Perhaps you could help me understand why leading.eigenvector.community runs on cache memory only for certain datasets and runs on external memory for different datasets, whereas other algorithms such as PageRank never fit entirely in cache memory for same datasets as before. The mathematical concept for both algorithms is very similar, and this is one of the issues that puzzle me.